# Counting the processes on linux in Golang

Tags: linux, plugins, go

I am working on a plugin that can count the processes running on a Linux system. I have searched around and it seems that I need to access /proc and gather information from there. I also tried using the os, os/exec, and syscall packages to run the external command `ps -A --no-headers | wc -l` but this isn't working either. I am coding this in golang as well. Any help or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You could scan the `/proc/` directory and count the numerical subdirectories there (like `/proc/1234`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the code that the Linux `ps` uses to iterate through the list of processes here:

https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/master/proc/readproc.c#L1167

In short, the algorithm is:

1. `opendir` on `/proc`
2. call `readdir` until an entry whose first character is a digit is returned.

So to count the number of processes, you can read through the entire directory and count how many entries match.

You can do this in Go using [`os.Open`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Open) to open `/proc`, and then call the `Readdirnames` method to list the processes.

Answer (score 1):

The following program works for me:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    out, err := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", "ps -A --no-headers | wc -l").Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Number of running processes: %s\n", out)
}
```

Note that you have to use `/bin/sh -c`. `exec.Command` executes a **single** program (an executable file), such as `/bin/sh` or `ps` or `tail`.

When you type `ps -A --no-headers | wc -l` in your command prompt this expression is interpreted by a shell program (such as `/bin/sh`) and the shell program launches two programs (`ps` and `wc`) and pipes (`|`) the output of the first program to the input of the second program.

`/bin/sh -c command` is equivalent to typing `command` in a terminal (with some minor differences, read `man sh` for more details).

Comment: This is very similar to my code but how can you go about testing this to make sure it's working? Sorry if this isn't the right question. I'm very new to Golang.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. When I compile this code and run the resulting application I see reasonable output. This code will not work on Windows or on play.golang.org. Probably you should start by reading https://golang.org/doc/install

Comment: When I run that program it prints out **[50 48 53 10]**. I ran `ps -A --no-headers | wc -l` right after this and saw that I have 205 processes running. If I'm reading the documentation correctly, the numbers your program is printing out are bytes. How do these numbers relate?

Comment: what version of Go are you using? Try changing `fmt.Printf("Number of running processes: %s\n", out)` to `fmt.Printf("Number of running processes: %s\n", string(out))`

Comment: That worked. I am using `go version go1.4`. New question for you: why did the `exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c"` need the `/bin/sh -c` part? I had the same for the rest of the command but it didn't work until I added in the part you had.

Comment: It looks like `%s` started to support `[]byte` only in Go 1.5. I have updated the answer with explanation about `/bin/sh -c`

Comment: This is inefficient and depends upon the `ps` and `wc`  programs, which might not be available (e.g. wrong `PATH`) or not runnable (`fork` failing)

Comment: I think it will be fast enough and will work on 99% of Linux systems. If you should use it or not depends on the requirements of your application.